# How to parse Json data, which is made by select mysql query?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

My server code is returning json data, which have select mysql query. Now I have to parse this information and I need to fill there json information into table, How I will do that?

**My server code**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');//Should work in Cross Domaim ajax Calling request
mysql_connect("localhost","root","2323");
mysql_select_db("service");

if(isset($_POST['type']))
{
    if($_POST['type']=="carpenter"){
        $startDate=$_POST['startDate'];
        $endDate=$_POST['endDate'];
        $query="select * from booking where scheduledDate between $startDate AND $endDate"; 
        $result=mysqi_query($query);
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);         
        $retVal=array();

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $$retVal[]=$row;
        }
        echo json_encode($retVal);
    }
} else{
    echo "Invalid Format";
}
```

**My script**

```
<script>
    function fetchData2(){
      $(".data-contacts2-js tbody").empty();
      var startDate=$('#datepicker1').val();
      var endDate=$('#datepicker2').val();
      $.ajax({
              url: "http://localhost/service/cleaning.php",
              type:"POST",
              dataType:"json",
              data:{type:"carpenter", startDate:startDate, endDate:endDate},
              ContentType:"application/json",
              success: function(response){                           
                 alert(obj);
             },
             error: function(err){
                alert("fail");
            }       
        });             
     }  

     $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".data-contacts2-js tbody").empty();               
         $('#fetchContacts2').click(function() {
                 fetchData2();
         });
      });

 </script>
```

**My html code**

```
<div class="block-content collapse in">
      <div class="span12">
        <table class="data-contacts2-js table table-striped" >
             <thead>
                    <tr>
                          <th>ID</th>
                          <th>Customer Name</th>
                          <th>Customer Mobile</th>
                          <th>Customer Email</th>
                          <th>Address</th>
                          <th>Date</th>
                          <th>Time</th>
                          <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
          </thead>
             <tbody>

             </tbody>
      </table>                                  
  </div>
 <button id="fetchContacts2" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Refresh</button>                         
          </div>
```

My Json format is

```
[
    {
        "b_id": "101",
        "cust_name": "qwq",
        "cust_mobile": "323232323",
        "cust_email": "u@gmail.com",
        "cust_address": "kslaksl",
        "scheduledDate": "2015-02-26",
        "scheduledTime": "14:30:00",
        "sc_id": "3",
        "sps_id": "1"
    }
]
```

**My dataBase table:**
[image]

Comment: you could build your markup table rows from the response using `$.each` then just `.html(markup)` on the `tbody`. is this a typo? `$result=mysqi_query($query);`

Comment: @Ghost, thanks for reply, could you explain much more..

Comment: could u show ur json response

Comment: @Outlooker, thanks for reply, I add my database snapshot, please see it, I am new in JSon, I dn't know How would be response..

Comment: @neelabhsingh just use that function inside the success block, `$.each(response, function(index, element){ // build html here });` and remove that `ContentType:"application/json",` you don't need that

Comment: @Ghost, Why we don't need contentType..

Comment: @neelabhsingh you don't need your content type to be json, just leave it so it defaults to form-urlencoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **$.each()** function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array. In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time. Inside the ajax success try the each function and loop through the response data that has been received from the `php` file.Hope that gives you an idea mate.. :)

```
        success: function(response){                           
             $.each(response, function(idx, obj) {
                $('table tbody').append(
                $('<tr>')
                    .append($('<td>').append(obj.id))
                    .append($('<td>').append(obj.cust_email))
                    .append($('<td>').append(obj.cust_mobile))
                );
             });
         },
```

**FYI**

[$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: yes `idx` means index..check the updated answer mate.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `$.each` and start building your markup table rows, then putting it inside the `tbody` tag.

You could just build them inside the success block. Here's the basic idea.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/service/cleaning.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {type:"carpenter", startDate:startDate, endDate:endDate},
    success: function(response){                
        var rows = '';           
        $.each(response, function(index, element){
            rows += '<tr>'; // build the row
                $.each(element, function(key, val){
                    rows += '<td>' + val + '</td>'; // build the value
                });
            rows += '</tr>';
        });
        $('table tbody').html(rows);
    }   
});
```

Sidenote: Based on your code, your mixing MySQLi and MySQL functions.

Obligatory Note:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

I suggest use PDO with prepared statements:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');//Should work in Cross Domaim ajax Calling request
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=service', 'root', '2323');
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
if(isset($_POST['type'])) {
    $startDate = $_POST['startDate'];
    $endDate = $_POST['endDate'];
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM booking WHERE scheduledDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate'; 
    $select = $db->prepare($query);
    $select->bindParam(':startDate', $startDate);
    $select->bindParam(':endDate', $endDate);
    $select->execute();

    $data = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: @neelabhsingh no you do not nee such thing